# Scheme's block structure efficiency

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

[The book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) defines *block structure* in Chapter 1, allowing you to 'package' `define`s inside a procedure definition.

Consider this `mean-square` definition for example:

```lisp
(define (mean-square x y) 
    (define (square x) (* x x))
    (define (average x y) (/ (+ x y) 2))
    (average (square x) (square y)))
```

when I run `(mean-square 2 4)` I correctly get `10`.

My question is, are the internal definitions ( `square` and `average` in this toy case ) run **each time** I invoke the `mean-square` procedure via the interpreter? If so, isn't that inefficient? and if not, why?

Comment: Modern compilers can deal with this easily. Here's one possible way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting

Comment: For this particular case, many compilers will inline the local functions away entirely. Racket does, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is somewhat naively compiled, there could be some overhead. The reason is that the inner functions are defined in a brand new lexical environment that is freshly instantiated on each entry into the function. In the abstract semantics, each time the function is called, new lexical closures have to be captured and wired into the correct spots in that environment frame.

Thus it boils down to how much of this can the compiler optimize away. For instance it can notice that neither of the functions actually references the surrounding lexical environment. (The `x` and `y` references in these functions are to their own parameters, not to those of the surrounding `mean-square`). Which means they both be moved to the top level without changing semantics:

```
(define (__anon1 x) (* x x))

(define (__anon2 x y) (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (mean-square x y)
    (define square __anon1)
    (define average __anon2)
    (average (square x) (square y)))
```

And since now `square` and `average` are effectively simple aliases (aliases for global entities that are generated by the compiler, which the compiler knows aren't being manipulated by anything outside of its control), the values they denote can be propagated through:

```
(define (mean-square x y)
  (__anon2 (__anon1 x) (__anon1 y)))
```

Comment: `new lexical closures have to be captured and wired into the correct spots in that environment frame`

This is what I was afraid of, said better than I ever could! Thanks  for the careful explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem. When the `mean-square` procedure is compiled, all the nested procedures are also compiled. It doesn't need to re-compile them every time you invoke the `mean-square` procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers have probably convinced you that the case you give really doesn't need to have any overhead: the local definitions can be just compiled away.  But it's worth thinking about how a system might approach cases where this *can't* be done.

Consider a definition like this:

```
(define (make-searcher thing)
  (define (search in)
    (cond [(null? in)
           #f]
          [(eqv? (first in) thing)
           in]
          [else (search (rest in))]))
  search)
```

Well, the local `search` procedure definitely can't be compiled away here, because it's returned from `make-searcher`.  And it's even worse than that:  `(make-searcher 1)` and `(make-searcher 2)` need to return *different* procedures, because `((make-searcher 1) '(1 2 3))` is `(1 2 3)` while `((make-searcher 2) '(1 2 3))` is `(2 3)`.

So this sounds completely hopeless: the local `search` procedure not only has to be a procedure (it can't be compiled away), it has to be remade each time.

But in fact things are not nearly so bad.  Lexical scope means that the system can know exactly what bindings are visible to `search` (in this case, a binding for `thing` as well as its argument).  So what you can do, for instance, is compile a bit of code which looks up the values of these bindings in a vector.  Then, the thing that is returned from `make-search` packs together the compiled code of `search` with a vector of bindings. The compiled code is always the same, only the vector needs to be created and initialised each time.

Comment: Your case is indeed interesting, thanks for pointing it out. I'll probably have to re-read it after I'm done with a few more chapters though ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this code:

```
(let ((a expr))
  (do-something-with a))
```

It is the same as:

```
((lambda (a)
   (do-something-with a))
 expr)
```

In an interpreter it might create the lambda each time before calling it while other
languages might turn it into `(do-something-with expr)`. The report doesn't want to touch non functional requirements other than guaranteed tail recursion. In all the serious implementations lambdas are cheap.

Since you mention racket: 
File test_com.rkt

```
#lang racket
(define (mean-square x y) 
    (define (square x) (* x x))
    (define (average x y) (/ (+ x y) 2))
    (average (square x) (square y)))

(display (mean-square 2 4))
```

Terminal commands:

```
raco make test_com.rkt
raco decompile compiled/test_com_rkt.zo
```

Resulting output:

```
(module test_com ....
  (require (lib "racket/main.rkt"))
  (provide)
  (define-values
   (mean-square)
   (#%closed
    mean-square49
    (lambda (arg0-50 arg1-51)
      '#(mean-square #<path:/home/westerp/compiled/test_com.rkt> 2 0 14 136 #f)
      '(flags: preserves-marks single-result)
      (/ (+ (* arg0-50 arg0-50) (* arg1-51 arg1-51)) '2))))
  (#%apply-values print-values (display '10)) ; the only code that matters!
  (void)
  (module (test_com configure-runtime) ....
    (require '#%kernel (lib "racket/runtime-config.rkt"))
    (provide)
    (print-as-expression '#t)
    (void)))
```

While `mean-square` has got their local procedures inlined, because I gave it literal values it will never call it so all it does is `(display '10)` and then exit.

This is of course if you do `make` or `exe`. From DrRacket the language options that enabled debugging and better trace and error messages will run slower.